# Emacs-jedi: jedi:instal-server fails "AttributeError:

Tags: python, emacs, emacs-jedi

I get an error when running `jedi:install-server` which I don't know how to fix:

```
  Running setup.py install for jediepcserver
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>
      File \"/tmp/pip-MLAXK5-build/setup.py\", line 25, in <module>
        **args
      File \"/home/ehere/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py\", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File \"/home/ehere/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py\", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File \"/home/ehere/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py\", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File \"/home/ehere/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py\", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File \"/home/ehere/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py\", line 575, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File \"/home/ehere/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py\", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File \"/home/ehere/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py\", line 971, in run_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File \"/home/ehere/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py\", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File \"/home/ehere/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py\", line 16, in finalize_options
        self.set_undefined_options('install',('install_layout','install_layout'))
      File \"/home/ehere/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py\", line 302, in set_undefined_options
        getattr(src_cmd_obj, src_option))
      File \"/home/ehere/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py\", line 105, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError, attr
    AttributeError: install_layout
    Complete output from command /home/ehere/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/python2 -c \"import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-MLAXK5-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\\r\\n', '\\n'), __file__, 'exec'))\" install --record /tmp/pip-uD7aIs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ehere/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/include/site/python2.7:
    running install
```

Strangly I can install jediepcserver manually using `pip -U /path/to/jedi-core/`, but somehow when running it from inside emacs it does not work.  Anyone has a clue what is going on here?